# Shared cookie between two client on the same machinefor java script Date the local time

Tags: c#, angular, cookies

I have noticed that cookie is shared by two clients running on the same machine and talking to the same remote server.
By sharing I mean that when the server is sending back a cookie to one of the client the other client will see the same value.
That creates a problem for me because I am working on the existing app that is automatically logging-in the client based on the received cookie.
Is there any known method to remedy the problem and have unique cookie per client (on the same computer) ?

Comment: Do you observe it on localhost?

Comment: On the client machine. That client machine has its name rejkid.hopto.org:8443 if that is what you are asking?